# How to include jszip with requirejs : jszip is not defined

Tags: javascript, excel, requirejs, xlsx, js-xlsx

I am using the [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) library to create an Excel file in JavaScript.

This library use `jszip`. I tried to define the `jszip` library in my JavaScript file before loading `jszip` but `jszip` is never defined:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jszip is not a function
```

**Config requirejs:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  requirejs.config({
    paths : {
      jszip : '../tools/jszip'
    }
  });
</script>
```

Here is how I use it in my JS file:

```
define(['jszip', '../tools/xlsx'], function(jszip, xlsx) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

JSZip (and ODS to support ods extension) must be loaded and attached to the window before XLSX is loaded.
I'm getting it working using shim with a custom "xlsx-loader":

**main.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        ods: '...path to ods',
        jszip: '...path to jszip',
        xlsxloader: '...path to xlsx-loader',
        xlsx: '...path to xlsx'
    },
    shim: {
        xlsx: {
            exports: 'XLSX',
            deps: ['xlsxloader']
        }
    }
});
```

**xlsx-loader.js**

```
define(['jszip', 'ods'], function (jszip, ods) {
    "use strict";

    window.JSZip = jszip;
    window.ODS = ods;
});
```

**your JS file**

```
define(['xlsx'], function () {
    // Do what you want with XLSX
    ...
```

Option 2) You can also achieve this chaining requires, it doesn't need any shim but doesn't work with *optimizer*

```
require(['jszip', 'ods'], function (jszip, ods) {
    window.JSZip = jszip;
    window.ODS = ods;
    require(['xlsx'], function () {
        // Do what you want with XLSX
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Should be marked as the answer for sure!  You've no only solved the problem, but done it "correctly" with the shim and xlsx loader.

Answer (score -1):

if you open xlsx.js, you would see there is a global variable named JSZip is used and that actually populates value of jszip. So if you change your function definition like this

```
define(['jszip', '../tools/xlsx'], function(JSZip , xlsx) {
```

it should work , I think

Comment: The code you show here is not functionally different from the code I have in my answer. The first argument to the callback to define could be `jszip`, `JSZip`, `potato`, `flalalalalala`, or whatever you want.

Answer (score -1):

Your must define the lib var as the constructor's name.

For my case i had the same issue:

```
define("Statistics", ["jquery", "underscore", "Datatable", "moment", "jszip"], function($, _, Datatable, moment, jszip) {
```

and i **changed jszip to JSZip** like this:

```
define("Statistics", ["jquery", "underscore", "Datatable", "moment", "jszip"], function($, _, Datatable, moment, JSZip) {
```